# Flexbox: make items fill in spaces between rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with some items that leave space and cannot continue filling spaces between rows

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-start { 
  justify-content: flex-start; 
}

.flex-wrap{
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.row-only {
  flex-basis:79%;
}

.growing-item {
  height: 300px !important;
  flex-basis: 15%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container flex-start flex-wrap">
  <li class="flex-item growing-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item row-only">5</li>
</ul>
```

What it looks like now:

[image: flex_now]

What I want it to look like:

[image: flex_expected]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: U can use case grid layout

Comment: @DeepshikaS The thing is that I need it to be flex (I have some styles for mobile) and i think it can be doable but I'm just not that good at CSS.

Comment: It must be an unordered list?

Comment: Not possible with flexbox and the current HTML structure.

Comment: @Sfili_81 No, it can be any kind of item. It's just styles.

Comment: @Paulie_D Why is not posible with flexbox?

Comment: Because flexbox won't you. That's not the way flex wrapping works. Once it wraps the element goes to the next row following the height of the tallest element as you have found. You would have to change the structure to achieve this in flexbox.

Comment: I'll make a little example of what do you want [https://jsfiddle.net/pwydu8cn/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/pwydu8cn/1/) IT is a point to start, try to achieve your solution.

Comment: to reproduce the screen shot, float does the job : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GRgzRLo  , a mixed of inline-block + float + formating context would also. this is not a typical flex layout, probably a grid layout if size are known